# GitHub - 2 Developers working at the same time

Tags: github

Some friends of mine and me are trying to code an application. We are probably going to using the *Eclipse IDE* and also want to use *GitHub* (because we heard, it is the leading platform for team-developments).

I think, I understood this whole Push, Pull and Commit thing.
Let's say my friend is pushing a new update for our project; but in the meantime I'm working on something else in the same project. What happens if I pull the updated version? Will the code, which just i wrote, be overwritten by the GitHub-project?
If yes, is there any way to prevent this in a simple way?

Comment: Come one, read the git book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2. It's free, and it's all explained. You could also just try, and see what happens.

Comment: [Git hello world](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/)

Answer (score 1):

No , when someone pushes at a remote server in your case GitHub , only the remote branches gets updated . When you pull from the remote server the **remote** branches in your local computer gets updated to their new position , however you **local** master branch remains the same , you can merge your master branch with that of the **remote** master branch in order to combine your works . If same file has been edited , then there will be conflicts and you have to resolve them using some merge tool . However if no same files are edited then merging will be smooth. If you want to ignore your friend's work just rebase your commit over his

Comment: No. Pulling first fetches, then merges or rebases (depending on the configuration)